# ScrollSpy with AngularJS and Waypoint (no-framework)

Tags: html, css, angularjs, triggers, angular-ui-bootstrap

We have made a **ScrollSpy UI** component that get's activated when it's content reaches **top of screen**. And once user scrolls down through Scrollspy's content, everything moves out of screen and footer scrolls up.

In addition to scroll-nav I also have a gist of content on left **positioned Fixed** which remains in view till content is scrolled.

I'm using Angular UI Bootstrap, and **Waypoint** to trigger start of ScrollSpy behavior

<del>[Earlier Approach](https://www.townscript.com/e/gids16)</del>  and  <del>[Current Approach](https://www.tsdugout.in/e/bob)</del>

In **Earlier Approach** I made "Left gist section" and "Scroll nav" `position: fixed` and content margin-left 25% and again "Left gist section" and "Scroll nav" `position Static/Absolute` after footer comes in viewport (triggered by WayPoint)
Which is making it very irregular and random, also "Scroll nav", "gist section" moves out before footer comes, sometimes gets triggered before it reaches top

In **Recent approach**, I made "Scroll nav" etc positioned absolute and content with `Overflow: scroll` and `height: 760px` and made the scrollbar of this section `Hidden` but the problem now is that when you don't scroll over that content or use Side main scrollbar no effect happens. and as height is 760px the content is not visible, user gets no idea of what is happening